# InvalidSelectorException while selecting value from the dropdown

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, automated-tests

I am trying to select value from the drodown. this is my code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[equals(text(),'60091 - AFCENT')]")).click();
```

Now here i have hardcoded the value, which works perfect but i am reading my testdata from excel file . so instead of using direct hard code values , i want to declare my testdata in xpath and read it from excel file. so i tried to this:
**Efforts**

```
 public void combobox(String testData) 
        {
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[equals(text(),'"+testData+"')]")).click();
    }
```

But i am getting the exception

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[equals(text(),'60091 - AFCENT')] because of
>   the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on
>   'Document': The string '//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[equals(text(),'60091
>   - AFCENT')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

**I tried to change it to "+testData+" too instead of using '"+testData+"'**
But same exception.

I tried this code too:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li"));
        for (WebElement option : options) {
          if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
            option.click();
        }
```

which works perfect but after this code execution , it is making my browser to wait for about 15 secs before executing next step or for quit too. **i am not getting Why so ?**

Please need suggestion or any ideas..

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint in your code and see what the value of `testData` is before it is used. It's likely that something is wrong with it since it works hardcoded and doesn't work as a variable. You should test your XPaths in the Chrome dev console using `$x()` to make sure everything is good before trying to run your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First: the exception you have got is because you xpath: `//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[equals(text(),'60091 - AFCENT')]` is not correct syntax.
Second: the code that you can run is not make your browser wait for 15s, it's just because problem about internet connection or you computer is a little slow.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'ui-id-1']/descendant::li[text() = '" + testData + "']"))).click();. I tried with this too. And internet and computer both are not slow. it just like for that piece of code , it is making webdriver to wait. and for first code with hardcoded value it is fast .

Comment: You must clear between multiple block of code. The code you said that works but slow on the question is difference than in this comment. In this comment, you have using the `WebDriverWait` util element visibility, it can can for 5 sec to make a action. Please specify your question again and modify the question clearly to get help. Your current question is a mess

Comment: i edited it. i just want to use string testData instead of direct hard code value. in my question i gave two codes that i tired. for the first one i have used direct value and for the second one i am declaring string.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your fast attempt *works perfect* as `xpath` doesn't have `equals`. You would have gotten the same exception. To check for text equality use `=`

```
"//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[text()='"+testData+"']"
```

You can also use `contains`

```
"//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]"
```

Comment: @PayalDhameliya What happened when you tries this? ant exception?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]")).click();. This worked. I gave delay for next test step. Thank you :)